# Angular OrderBy with dynamic headers

Tags: angularjs

How can I sort a table given dynamic headers with angular? All of the examples I can find use static headers. My first issue is that ng-click isn't updating orderByField.

My best shot below: HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-condesnsed table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in report_headers" 
            ng-click="orderByField[header]; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            {{ header }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="quote in paginated_quotes">
        <td ng-repeat="elem in quote |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
          <span ng-if="!isNumber(elem.value)">
              {{ elem.value | limitTo:8 }}... {{ elem.unit }}</span>
          <span ng-if="isNumber(elem.value)">
              {{ elem.value | number:0 }} {{ elem.unit }}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'UUID';
$scope.reverseSort = false;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
<th ng-repeat="header in report_headers" 
        ng-click="orderByField = header; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
```

other than that it looks like it should work